# ListView Item Added Event

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there an event that I could use that occurs when an Item is added to a listView?

Comment: Check out this post from me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041069/add-event-handler-for-listview-items-added/21264244#21264244 You dont need to edit other source!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't think so.

I have used this [listview replacement](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) in the past.  I'm fairly sure it has an event for when an item is added.