# Add event handler for ListView Items_added

Tags: c#, winforms

In C# Windows Form Application; Is there an event handler for the ListView control that is fired when items are added to the listview items ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [ListView Item Added Event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2024401/listview-item-added-event)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would [see here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/observerlistview.aspx)  or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47169/is-there-an-event-that-triggers-if-the-number-of-listviewitems-in-a-listview-chan).  They are more or less the same answer, just written in very different styles.  Short version, add ItemAdded event to ListViewItemCollection.

Answer (score 13):

**You dont need to edit other source!**

Ok: change from ListView to myListView

Long time ago - but i search for an solution without implements with own ItemAdd-Function!
The best way to do it... use the WndProc-Function.

Message: LVM_INSERTITEM

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

```
//COMMCTRL.H
#define LVM_FIRST               0x1000           // ListView messages
#define LVM_INSERTITEMA         (LVM_FIRST + 7)  
#define LVM_INSERTITEMW         (LVM_FIRST + 77) 
//edit itemremove (LVM_DELETEITEM)
#define LVM_DELETEITEM          (LVM_FIRST + 8)
```

C#-implementation

```
class myListView : ListView {

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m){
        base.WndProc(ref m);

        switch (m.Msg){
            case 0x1007:    //ListViewItemAdd-A
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Item added (A)");
                break;
            case 0x104D:    //ListViewItemAdd-W
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Item added (W)");
                break;
            //edit for itemremove
            case 0x1008:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Item removed");
                break;
            case 0x1009:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Item removed (All)");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can fire your own ItemAddedEvent. I hope that helps other people, who have the same issue.

gegards raiserle

(edit: please vote ;) )

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info, may I ask what is the message or case for item removed?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774895%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

look at my post :D

Comment: A note for future explorers... There's a specific message for "All items removed", value 0x1009  ;)

Answer (score 5):

There is no event that do that.
But you can always create your own list box:

```
public class MyListView : ListView
{
    public void AddItem(ListViewItem item)
    {
        Items.Add(item);
        if (ItemAdded != null)
            ItemAdded.Invoke(this, new ItemsAddedArgs(item));
    }

    public EventHandler<ItemsAddedArgs> ItemAdded;
}

public class ItemsAddedArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ItemsAddedArgs(ListViewItem item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public object Item { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to hold the items in an instance of the ObservableCollection class, set ListView.ItemsSource to that collection and subscribe to the ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged event.

Comment: Sadly, `Forms ListView` doesn't have an `ItemsSource`. That is a `WPF` improvement.

Answer (score 0):

The framework does **not** define an event such as `ItemAdded`. However, make sure to visit this workaround: [An Observer Pattern and an Extended ListView Event Model](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/observerlistview.aspx). For example, the following events are defined there:

```
public event ListViewItemDelegate ItemAdded; 
public event ListViewItemRangeDelegate ItemRangeAdded; 
public event ListViewRemoveDelegate ItemRemoved; 
public event ListViewRemoveAtDelegate ItemRemovedAt;
```