# C# - Fire Event if number of listview items is bigger than 200

Tags: c#, multithreading, listview, events

I'm looking for a way to call the method DoAnalysis if the number of listview items is bigger than e.g. 200.

As I'm working with multithreading and couldn´t find a suitable way to find out when the threads have finished their work(finish = all listview items added) without losing performance, I now have to check it this way.

So I need an event that tells me when item count of listview is bigger than a specific number so that it then calls the method "doAnalysis" which then will analyze the listview items.

Comment: I am surprized that's much harder task than I would thought. Is it winform? WPF? For winforms you can use [winapi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21264244/1997232) of the control itself. In WPF you have to monitor for `ItemsSource` collection (whatever that would be), rather use MVVM to handle collection changes without the view.

Comment: If you show some code, then we could give you some examples which an range from creating your own list type to just check it from your threads and fire the event from there. To see if threads are finished you can use various methods, which doesn't require a lot of performance. The key is: show us your code.